Why does this redundant type hint dispel a warning?
This is a snippet from my solution for Advent of Code 2024 day 6, in Python 3.12:
CoordType = typing.TypeVar("CoordType", bound=tuple[int | float, ...])
def coord_add(coords1:CoordType, coords2:CoordType) -> CoordType:
    return tuple(map(operator.add, coords1, coords2))

def walk_around() -> tuple[bool, set[tuple[int, int]]]:
    guard = guard_start

    # heading north
    move = (-1, 0)
    # where we've stepped
    visited = set()
    visited.add(guard)
    # transitions (guard, next) where we bonked into obstacles
    bonked = set()
    next = coord_add(guard, move)
    while in_bounds(grid, *next):
        if grid[next[0]][next[1]] == '#':
            if (guard, next) in bonked:
                # this is a loop!
                return True, visited
            bonked.add((guard, next))
            # turn right
            move = (move[1], -move[0])
        else:
            # take the step
            guard = next
            visited.add(guard)
        next = coord_add(guard, move)
    return False, visited

_, visited = walk_around()
print(len(visited))

loop_count = 0
for (r, c) in visited:
    if grid[r][c] == '^':
        continue
    # add an obstacle
    grid[r][c] = '#'
    loop, _ = walk_around()
    grid[r][c] = '.'
    if loop:
        loop_count += 1
print(loop_count)

If I leave out the type hint on walk_around(), I get a warning that the inferred types of r and c at the bottom are Any instead of int and therefore aren't suitable to index a list, even though the inferred type of walk_around() is still exactly the same that the hint gave, and the inferred type of visited is still set[tuple[int, int]]. Why does the inference just kind of fall over in the absence of this hint, which is hinting something it already knew?
(If it matters, this is on IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 with v243 of the Python plugin, equivalent to Pycharm 2024.3.)

Please show us the actual error or warning messages you get. Copy-paste the full and complete output into your question.

I'm adding pycharm because this really is a problem with the type analysis engine used in PyCharm (and by extension other IntelliJ IDEs for analysing Python code). I would not rely on PyCharm's engine for type-checking - it's great at code navigation, refactoring, and code completion/suggestions, but not so much for strict type-checking; I suggest relying on mypy or pyright for that.

Your type hint isn't redundant; it's what prevents the return type from being inferred as Any. (mypy also requires it, though PyRight can infer a more specific return type.)
